# Can somebody suggest good learning source of IMS?

Tags: database, db2, mainframe, ims-db

I would like to learn working with `IMS`, can somebody suggest me a good source? I'm not sure if it matters to say that I have quite good exposure and experience with `INSYNC DB2` and `QMF`. So anything that can depict and explain the advantages and disadvantages over `IMS` would be really helpful. Please provide me a good page where i get good explanation and hands on scope.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try for the below listed books.

1. IMS for the Cobol Programmer, Part 1: Data Base Processing With Ims/Vs and Dl/I Dos/Vs By Steve Eckols
2. IMS for the Cobol Programmer, Part 2: Data Communications and Message Format Service (Pt.2) by Steve Eckols
3. I. M. S. Programming Techniques: Guide to Using D. L./1 by Dan Kapp and Joseph F. Lebe

Option 3 is a very good book which gives very well structured examples. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

[IBM IMS Tutorials](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ieduasst/stgv1r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.iea.fileman/fileman/6.1z/FMIMS.html)

If you're interested in books, you can serach Amazon for IBM IMS.